# Some devices can't connect using new WiFi password

Tags: wireless-networking, passwords

I am using a Fritz!Box 6490 and provide a guest WiFi to selected people. The security settings are `WPA2+WPA3` and I use a 14-letter password.

After a couple of weeks I changed the password to a 16-letter password. Using this new password some devices could connect to the WiFi while others (a Win10 laptop and an older Android smartphone) could not. There were no visible error-messages besides from the quite generic "Can not connect to this WiFi-network" on Windows.

I changed back to the old password and all devices could connect again.

Are there any limitations on WiFi passwords or bugs in old software that render certain passwords unusable to some devices?

Comment: Aside from *length*, were there any other changes to the password, such as including non-alphanumeric characters? It might be useful to test a long password with *just* alphanumeric characters to prove if string length is the only issue.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Both passwords consist of uppercase letters, lowercase letters, and two non-alphanumeric characters (but still ASCII). Those two non-alphanumeric characters are the same for both passwords.

Answer (score 0):

I've had devices connected with WP2+WPA3 router that gave me lots of headaches. Better stick with WPA2 exclusively till you get rid of the older devices.